# tinyMCE textpattern plugin is not changing the text as per the patterns specified

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm having real trouble with tinyMCE's textpattern plugin, which just simply doesn't appear to work. The code below is as basic as I can make it with an example taken directly from the tinyMCE website. But, if I type (c) (for-instance), and then press space or enter (as directed), nothing happens. I would expect tinyMCE to change it. What am I doing incorrectly?

````
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>

        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
            plugin: 'textpattern',
            textpattern_patterns: [
                {start: '---', replacement: '<hr/>'},
                {start: '--', replacement: '—'},
                {start: '-', replacement: '—'},
                {start: '(c)', replacement: '©'},
                {start: '//brb', replacement: 'Be Right Back'},
                {start: '//heading', replacement: '<h1 style="color: blue">Heading here</h1> <h2>Author: Name here</h2> <p><em>Date: 01/01/2000</em></p> <hr />'},
            ]
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In taking your configuration and using TinyMCE Fiddle these things seem to be working fine:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/zwhaab

Do they work for you there?  If so there is likely something else in your application impacting things.

Comment: Thanks, yes they do work fine in the fiddle. I can't think what it would be in my application, do you have any ideas? I'm running wamp locally. There's nothing in the console and it doesn't work in FF or Chrome.

Comment: It is really hard to say as those are both supported browsers.  Are you doing anything to intercept keystrokes or the like?  If you are loading a variety of other libraries you could remove them all and add them back one at a time until things break.

Answer (score 0):

Please also make sure you're using correct name with your TinyMCE version.
As noted in the [TinyMCE 6.0 Release Notes](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/6.0-release-notes-core-changes/#removed-or-deprecated-options-textpattern), the `textpattern_patterns` option:

- Was renamed to `text_patterns`;
- Had its functionality moved to the Core of TinyMCE 6.0.

As well, the `textpattern API` has been removed.

Finally, and unlike in previous versions of TinyMCE, text patterns are now on by default. `text_patterns: false` turns the functionality off.